# Whats the right way to redirect when data is not found with Redux and Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I've got a redux state like this:

```
{
  currentItemId: 1,
  items: [{id: 1, name: 'todo 1'}, ...]
}
```

When `currentItemId` is set, the app displays the item's detail.

Now in a rare case when the currentItem is set to ID that doesn't represent an item in items array, I want to redirect back.

A good place to catch that seems the `connect` of our `ItemForm`, where I can issue a redirect.

The problem is, that it complains about calling `setState` and maybe all I need to do is to schedule it for later.

I also want to make sure I don't show the `ItemForm` in case the item could not be found.

Whats the right thing to do in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

How you redirect differs slightly depending on which routing method you are using. Assuming that you are using react-router-dom I would just do a redirect either in render or componentDidMount. Assuming that you map your currentItemId to a prop for your component you could do something like the following using [withRouter HOC](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(!this.props.currentItemId) { // Or whatever value you want to check for
        this.props.history.push('/redirectpageurl');
    }
}
```

Another way to do redirects in react-router-dom is to render a [Redirect component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).

```
render() {
    if(!this.props.currentItemId) {
        return <Redirect to="/redirectpageurl" />
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like `componentWillMount` is better, since its triggered before render (and I don't want and can't render without complete data). It seems like the removal of onEnter suggests using lifecycle method as well https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3854

Comment: This HOC looks like the right solution, since I would have to 1) remove isRequired in all my props 2) have both componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps in a component that shouldn't really be even touched if the data isn't there. https://medium.com/@francoisz/react-router-v4-unofficial-migration-guide-5a370b8905a#e85f